# What does this set of Parenthesis mean in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6

I have the following line of code:

```
varReturn(1) = intNewShippingID
```

What do the parenthesis around the 1 mean? Is this setting the max length of 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sets the first element on the `varReturn` **array**.

Comment: +1. Here is the VB6 manual introductory topic on arrays http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261364(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: It could also be assigning a value to a local Property (Let) that takes an argument.

Answer (score 1):

`varReturn` is name of array

Note that in visual basic it is not necessary that `varReturn(1)` is first element. Thus `varReturn(1)` refers to array element having index 1